# I am looking for a way to fix the first column in a table component in react material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a way to fix the first column like [this website](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/fixed-columns/) on bottom.

How can I make the first columns fixed when scrolling?

(devexpress is useless)

Answer (score 14):

I found a way for handle this. For each first TableCell of TableRows I added an style class with the next properties

```
position: '-webkit-sticky',
position: 'sticky',
background: '#fff',
left: 0,
zIndex: 1,
```

There is a limitation, no border-button is shown on Firefox, testing in Edge works as spected.

[image: result]

Comment: best answer for just using css !

Comment: Any knowledge how we can apply this same to datagrid in Material UI because I have been trying there and no luck.